# What is the purpose of the string parameter of TabHost.newTabSpec?

Tags: android, android-layout

newTabSpec("tab1")

What is the purpose of the string parameter of TabHost.newTabSpec? "tab1" ?

will it be displayed anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it helps to identify TabSpec. More or less, its just like its Id